# Javascript- Event dosen't work with the other event

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, preventdefault

I'm trying to do "todo" app with pure javascript. I created a "newTask" event, it worked as well, after that I created `deleteTask` event and it worked too. But I realized that I can't create a new task with `deleteTask` event codes, if I remove deleteTask codes, it works again ?

What is my mistake in here ?

```js
const task = document.querySelector('#task');
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

form.addEventListener('submit', newTask);

document.body.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);

function newTask(e) {
  if (task.value) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = "collection-item";
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task.value));
    let href = document.createElement('a');
    href.className = "delete-item secondary-content";
    href.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';
    href.setAttribute('href', '#');
    li.appendChild(href);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  } else {
    alert('Please type something');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  form.reset();
}

function deleteTask(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-remove')) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div id="main" class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title">Task List</span>
            <div class="row">
              <p style="background-color:red;color:white;text-align:center" id="error"></p>
              <form id="task-form">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="task" id="task">
                  <label for="task">New Task</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
            <ul class="collection">
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn black" id="clear-tasks">Clear Tasks</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: perhaps the `e.preventDefault();` in `deleteTask` should be inside the `if` condition ONLY

Comment: Nothing changed :/

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Comment: Why don't you just do `href.addEventListener("click", deleteTask)` instead of adding the listener to the body?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ouc0o7sq/

Comment: I tried at the first, but I couldnt reach items with that way @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `e.preventDefault()` inside the `if`. Otherwise, it's preventing the `click` event from propagating to the other elements.

I know you said you tried that, but it works here.

```js
const task = document.querySelector('#task');
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

form.addEventListener('submit', newTask);

document.body.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);

function newTask(e) {
  if (task.value) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = "collection-item";
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task.value));
    let href = document.createElement('a');
    href.className = "delete-item secondary-content";
    href.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove">X</i>';
    href.setAttribute('href', '#');
    li.appendChild(href);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  } else {
    alert('Please type something');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  form.reset();
}

function deleteTask(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-remove')) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div id="main" class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title">Task List</span>
          <div class="row">
            <p style="background-color:red;color:white;text-align:center" id="error"></p>
            <form id="task-form">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" name="task" id="task">
                <label for="task">New Task</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
          <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item">
              List Item
              <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
              List Item
              <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
              List Item
              <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
              List Item
              <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
              List Item
              <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <button class="btn black" id="clear-tasks">Clear Tasks</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But May I ask something ? `e.preventDefault()` is in a function, it should work in this function locally. why does it prevent other function or event?

Answer (score 0):

The following event handler captures **all** clicks on the body:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);
```

So when you prevent the default behaviour on click in your `deleteTask` function you also prevent the default action on the other buttons, including the "add task" button.

Given that you already check the target of the click you should also *only* prevent the default click action in that condition:

```
function deleteTask(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-remove')) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    e.preventDefault(); // Move preventDefault here
  }
}
```

```js
const task = document.querySelector('#task');
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

form.addEventListener('submit', newTask);

document.body.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);

function newTask(e) {
  if (task.value) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = "collection-item";
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task.value));
    let href = document.createElement('a');
    href.className = "delete-item secondary-content";
    href.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';
    href.setAttribute('href', '#');
    li.appendChild(href);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  } else {
    alert('Please type something');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  form.reset();
}

function deleteTask(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('fa-remove')) {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  //
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div id="main" class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title">Task List</span>
            <div class="row">
              <p style="background-color:red;color:white;text-align:center" id="error"></p>
              <form id="task-form">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="task" id="task">
                  <label for="task">New Task</label>
                </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn">
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
            <ul class="collection">
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="collection-item">
                List Item
                <a href="#" class="delete-item secondary-content">
                  <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn black" id="clear-tasks">Clear Tasks</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: But  e.preventDefault() is in a function, it should work in this function locally. why does it prevent other functions?

Comment: Simply because it is captured first, as `<body>` contains the other elements. You need only prevent the default action once. As soon as you have done it the click is disabled for the contained elements as well.